# About tree archeitecture and reactjs

Tags: reactjs, tree

While I was using react I kept asking myself about one cons of the tree module of reactjs.
let suppose that I am trying to add a new component to an old system.
The new component is under a father that doesn't contain the info I need.
but another father does.
I cannot change the other component in the tree. 
So my question: is how with the tree archetecutre of reactjs I can add a new component that looks for new information within a different branch of the tree.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Andy, please provide some code on what you have tried, your question as it exists is too broad.

Comment: let suppose that we got a choclate factory, that creates a choclate. each stage at the assembly line adds a canday to the choclate. all of the stages in the line are children of factroy. then we got the QA component which says to the manager of the factory whether the candy should be sent or not. Now the health minstry issues a new regulation that choclate cannot be bought in other country. the problem, that the line contains that info, while the ministry is a brother to the factory manager. so the ministry can't check from which country the choclate has been bought.So it can't reach that info